# finding the date range between two dates and the repeat the columns

Tags: python, sql

```
    A                       B               C
0   10062-35551-49007-45097 8/31/2014 0:00  233
1   10062-35551-49007-45097 10/31/2014 0:00 14
2   10062-35551-49007-45097 12/31/2014 0:00 22
```

I want the output as all the months between the date range of B and C should repeat in that date range, like:

```
    A                       B               C
0   10062-35551-49007-45097 8/31/2014 0:00  233
1   10062-35551-49007-45097 9/30/2014 0:00  233
2   10062-35551-49007-45097 10/31/2014 0:00 14
3   10062-35551-49007-45097 11/30/2014 0:00 14
4   10062-35551-49007-45097 12/31/2014 0:00 22
```

Comment: Would you please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: oracle, mysql, sql-server, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical way to adress this problem is to first create a reference table to hold the list of end-of-month dates. While this might seem a bit of an extra effort to start with, this has the advantage of making the query much simpler to write (and largely RDBMS-independant).

Say we create table `all_dates` and store all end-of-month dates for year 2014:

```
create table all_dates (dt date not null primary key);
insert into all_dates values('2014-01-31');
insert into all_dates values('2014-02-28');
insert into all_dates values('2014-03-31');
insert into all_dates values('2014-04-30');
insert into all_dates values('2014-05-31');
insert into all_dates values('2014-06-30');
insert into all_dates values('2014-07-31');
insert into all_dates values('2014-08-31');
insert into all_dates values('2014-09-30');
insert into all_dates values('2014-10-31');
insert into all_dates values('2014-11-30');
insert into all_dates values('2014-12-31');
```

Now we can write a query that:

- selects the relevant range of dates, based on the minimum and maximum values in column `B` of the original table
- joins each end-of-month date to the relevant record in the original table, using a `NOT EXISTS` condition

SQL:

```
SELECT t.A, d.dt B, t.C
FROM 
    all_dates d
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(B) minb, MAX(B) maxb FROM mytable
    ) trange  
        ON d.dt >= trange.minb AND d.dt <= trange.maxb 
    INNER JOIN mytable t
        ON t.B <= d.dt
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM mytable t1
            WHERE t1.B <= d.dt AND t1.B > t.B
        )
```

This **[demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9RCwcwf8LWQvCsSLVpudQ8/1)** with your sample data returns:

```
| A                       | B           | C   |
| ----------------------- | ----------- | --- |
| 10062-35551-49007-45097 | 2014-08-31  | 233 |
| 10062-35551-49007-45097 | 2014-09-30  | 233 |
| 10062-35551-49007-45097 | 2014-10-31  | 14  |
| 10062-35551-49007-45097 | 2014-11-30  | 14  |
| 10062-35551-49007-45097 | 2014-12-31  | 22  |
```

PS: since you did not state which RDBMS you are using, I chose MySQL; you might need to adapt the code that creates the `all_tables` reference table according to your real use case (but the final query would most probably remain unchanged).

---

Bonus: here is a query that would properly handle the use case where several distinct values are present in column `A`:

```
SELECT t.A, d.dt B, t.C
FROM 
    all_dates d
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT A, MIN(B) minb, MAX(B) maxb 
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY A
    ) trange  
        ON d.dt >= trange.minb AND d.dt <= trange.maxb 
    INNER JOIN mytable t
        ON trange.A = t.A
        AND t.B <= d.dt
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM mytable t1
            WHERE 
                t1.A = t.A 
                AND t1.B <= d.dt 
                AND t1.B > t.B
        )
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9RCwcwf8LWQvCsSLVpudQ8/2)**

Comment: the column b contains dates from 1975 to 2019 , so it won't be possible to create a reference table for all those years

Comment: @HermantKumar: that’s about 500 records to create, and you should be able to automate the generation of the INSERT commands with the tool of your choice (Excel for example). The way I see it, taking this one-shot action is less painful and error-prone than writing (and maintaining) a more complex query...

Comment: ya , that makes sense ,

Comment: what if i 2   10062-35551-49007-45097 12/31/2014 0:00 22have different A values in A column like :        A                       B               C
0   10062-35551-49007-45097 8/31/2014 0:00  233
1   10062-35551-49007-45097 10/31/2014 0:00 14
2   10062-35551-49007-45097 12/31/2014 0:00 22
3   10062-35551-49007-45028 12/31/2015      12
3   10062-35551-49007-45028 12/31/2016      23   In sql server

Comment: @HemantKumar: good point, I updated my answer with a slightly modified query for that use case.

Comment: thanks GMB , do you think , In the last select block, there has to be one more condition like , t1.A=t.A

Comment: @HemantKumar: you are absolutly right. Query fixed. Seems like you really master the logic of that query now!